# Draw a grid without labels and axis using d3

Tags: d3.js, grid

I would like to create a vertical grid using D3.

I know I could use d3 axis methods (like `axisBottom`, `axisLeft`, ...) and set `tickSize` to manage the grid lines size but the axis generators create not only the lines but also the axis and the labels and I don't need them.

For example, this is what I could draw using `axisBottom`:

```js
const container = d3.select('svg')
container.append('g').attr('class', 'vertical-grid')

const height = 100
const numberOfTicks = 5

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, 200])

const xGridGenerator = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickSize(height)
  .ticks(numberOfTicks)

container
  .select('.vertical-grid')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${0}, ${0})`)
  .call(xGridGenerator)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

This is what I would like to draw:

[image]

I'm interested only in the red and blue lines, no labels, no axes.

I have the `g` container, the two scales and the number of ticks.

How can I do that?

Honestly I don't know how to start

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. A simple way to do the customization is to modify the axes' elements (labels, line colors, etc.) after you've added them. For example:

```
xAxis.selectAll('text').remove()
xAxis.selectAll('line').attr('stroke', 'blue')
```

Here's a complete example that renders a version of what you want (though the width/height are a little off because you'd want to have some margin):

```js
const height = 200
const width = 200
const margin = { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 }
const container = d3.select('svg')
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
container.append('g').attr('class', 'vertical-grid')
container.append('g').attr('class', 'horizontal-grid')

const numberOfTicks = { x: 8, y: 4 }

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right ])

const xGridGenerator = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
  .tickSize(height - margin.top - margin.bottom)
  .ticks(numberOfTicks.x)

const xAxis = container
  .select('.vertical-grid')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${0}, ${0})`)
  .call(xGridGenerator)

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom ])

const yGridGenerator = d3.axisRight(yScale)
  .tickSize(width - margin.left - margin.right)
  .ticks(numberOfTicks.y)

const yAxis = container
  .select('.horizontal-grid')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${0}, ${0})`)
  .call(yGridGenerator)

// Customize
xAxis.selectAll('text').remove()
xAxis.selectAll('line').attr('stroke', 'blue')

yAxis.selectAll('text').remove()
yAxis.selectAll('line').attr('stroke', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so isn't there a way to do this without adding element to DOM and then remove them?

Comment: @sleepwalking: I don't believe there is a way to customize the way you want using the D3 API. The idea of removing/modifying axis elements _after_ adding them comes directly from the [Styled Axes example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/styled-axes) from Mike Bostock.